# Typescript function from another class

Tags: typescript

I am pretty new to typescript, but now I have a problem. 
I've written a function in Typescript out of every class

```
function someFunction(){
}
```

And now I wanted to call the function from another TS file and i declared it as follows:

```
declare function someFunction(): void;
```

But this won't work in the browser console I get the error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: someFunction() is not defined

File one looks like:

```
export class SomeClass{
}

export function someFunction(){
}
```

File two :

```
///<reference path="File1.ts" />
export class SomeOtherClass{
 someFunction();
}
```

Comment: Added example above :)

Comment: In this function is an algorithm which I wanna call from another class too. (Controller) So that I dont have to duplicate the code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to declare the function, you can reference the file that has it and then the compiler will know it.
For example:

```
// file1.ts

function someFunction(): string {
    ...
}
```

Use it:

```
// file2.ts

/// <reference path="file1.ts" />

let mystr = someFunction();
```

The error you are getting is a runtime error because you don't include `file1.js`:

```
<script src="file1.js" />
```

---

#### Edit

The code you added to your question compiles for me with two changes:

(1) removed exports:

```
// file1.ts

class SomeClass {}

function someFunction() {}
```

(2) added a class method:

```
// file2.ts

/// <reference path="file1.ts" />

class SomeOtherClass {
    fn() {
        someFunction();
    }
}
```

**Edit by Original Poster:**
Second Solution (worked for me)

```
// file1.ts

export function someFunction(){
    ...
}
```

Use it:

```
// file2.ts

import myFunc = require('./file1');

myFunc.someFunction();
```

Comment: The compiler doesn't recognize this function when I set a reference to the file...

Comment: Right, add `export`. I fixed my answer.

Comment: In file1.ts I added what you said export function etc. but It still won't load, i get a compiler error again

Comment: I checked it myself, and it works without the `export` that I've added (now removed). For me it works and I get no compilation errors. What are you getting?

Comment: I think I should say I work with VS Code and Gulp. The built in INtelliSense says "Cannot find name someFunction"       #update start post edit

Comment: And what does the compiler say?

Comment: The same, "cannot find name someFunction()"

Comment: Your code compiles for me just fine with two changes. Check my revised answer

Comment: And again doesnt work, I think I am wrong with the reference path? When the other file is in the same folder i just have to write "file.ts" right?

Comment: Yes. Or `"./file.ts"`. But the compiler would complain about not finding the file if that was the problem. Which version of typescript are you using?

Comment: According to the package.json from typescript i use 1.6.2

Comment: I'm pretty sure that 1.6 should deal with it, but as it's working for me in both `1.8.10` and `2.1.4`, maybe try to update it to a newer version.

Comment: After updating typescript to the latest version it still didn't work. Now I found the solution how to solve this problem, maybe you edit this to your post as "second" solution?   I added the keyword export to the function and in the other file2.ts  I made an import variableName = require('./file1.ts');  Now I can use the function with variableName.someMethod();

Answer (score -1):

I don't get exactly what you are trying to do, but in typescript defining a function is done like this:

```
public someFunction(): void {}
```

You can replace `public` with `private` or `protected` according to what you need, or even remove it

Calling from the browser should be done by the framework you use using events `(click)` etc

Comment: No, that's not a class method, it's a function outside of a class.