# call a function of another class in same component file

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 2 classes in the same `component.ts` file. one class is for embedding the `Doc blot` and another one is `component class`. so I have to call a function that resides in `component class` from `Doc blot class`. [i have tried this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41165155/typescript-function-from-another-class) but it wasn't working. it throws an error `Expected 12 arguments, but got 0.`. any help is very much appreciated.

xyz.component.ts

```
class DOCBlock extends Embed {
 foo() {
   let component = new SomeComponent()
    component.bar()
   }

 export class SomeComponent implements Oninit {
    contructor(12 arguments......) { }

    bar() { // magic happens here }
 }
```

Comment: You can pass the arguments here: let component = new SomeComponent(arg1, arg2, arg...12)

Comment: @sb32134 sorry that is not allowed

Comment: Could you post the full code. Your bracket block may be cause confuse. I saw the first block missing close bracket. That cause may be the second class is child of the first one.

Comment: @MonkaweeManeewalaya they are 2 separate classes

Answer (score 0):

When you call let component = new SomeComponent() where are the arguments for the constructor?  You have specified that the constructor takes 12 arguments but not provided any.  Do you need a constructor on DBCBlock that takes 12 arguments too, so it can forward them to SomeComponent's constructor?

Comment: Oops!  That was supposed to be a comment but I posted it as an answer by mistake.  I will leave it as it might help anyway.